# I tried to make a connection to alfresco using java with the help of alfresco sdk 3.4

Tags: java, alfresco

I m trying to implement alfresco sdk 3.4 to java. I made all the changes as per doc given from alfresco fourm. After doing that I got this error. Please tell where i m going wrong.

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'RepoServerMgmt' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionService' while setting bean property 'transactionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionService' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.alfresco.util.BaseApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(BaseApplicationContextHelper.java:67)
        at org.alfresco.util.ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(ApplicationContextHelper.java:46)
        at org.alfresco.sample.FirstFoundationClient.main(FirstFoundationClient.java:63)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionService' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
        ... 44 more
```

Comment: what a horrible post. Don't just post an unformatted error log. Explain your problem.

Comment: I m Sorry . In the above error I m trying to implement alfresco sdk in eclipse. So i m geeting above mention error

Comment: Then edit your question and add that description. Also show your code that caused this error. You have to give the details.

Answer (score 3):

When you run FirstFoundationClient, you are executing a Java program that runs the Alfresco server within the same process. When that program starts up the repository it needs to know information about your repo configuration. It does this by reading the alfresco-global.properties file. Inside that file you'll see things like dir.root, which points to a directory on your local file system where indexes and content lives, and you'll see a set of db.driver and db.url properties. Your error log appears to indicate that you have not set the db.driver and db.url appropriately. For example, if you are using MySQL, make sure the following is uncommented:

```
db.driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/alfresco
```

If you already have a working Alfresco repository running in Tomcat, you might want to grab your alfresco-global.properties file that is proven to work and copy it into the source folder for the FirstFoundationClient Eclipse project and try again. Make sure your Tomcat is not running when running this example from Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Jeff Potts Thanks for ur reply . I uncommented the db. driver and db.url also. But it does nt work.